# AWS S3 & Serverless - Access Denied when using PUT presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I'm trying to generate presigned URLs to upload objects to an S3 bucket but whenever I execute the PUT requests to the presigned URLs, I get 'Access Denied' errors. This is the code I am using to generate the URLs (runs inside a node lambda function):

```js
app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    const filename = `${uuid()}.jpg`;

    const url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
        Bucket: BucketName,
        Key: filename,
        Expires: 3600,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        ACL: 'public-read',
    });

    res.status(200).json({ url, filename });
});
```

And here are the permissions from my `serverless.yml` file:

```yaml
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  profile: my-profile
  region: eu-west-2
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 's3:PutObject'
        - 's3:PutObjectAcl'
      Resource:
        - !GetAtt galleryBucket.Arn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was applying the `PutObject` and `PutObjectAcl` permissions to the `galleryBucket` instead of the objects within it.

**You must apply the `PutObject` permission to the objects inside the bucket, not the bucket itself**

I updated my permissions to this and the PUT requests succeeded:

```yaml
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  profile: my-profile
  region: eu-west-2
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 's3:PutObject'
        - 's3:PutObjectAcl'
      Resource:
        Fn::Join: ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref galleryBucket, '/*']]
```

**Note the `/*` at the end of the resource identifier**